# node.js server call not responding on Windows Server 2008

Tags: node.js

I created a node.js application which runs fine on 2 laptops.
Now I want to install it on a windows 2008 server.

I copied the files, installed all programs needed (express, mssql).
I can start my server, which goes well.

This is the code for starting the server :

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

And when I start it with node server.js I see : Listening on port 3000.

But when I try to do a call from my browser, nothing happens. No error, nothing. What am I missing here? I also tried other ports, and using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, but nothing works ...

Thanks for any advice on this one.

THis is the complete server.js file :

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var express = require('express');

var config = {
user: 'xx',
password: 'xxxxxxx',
server: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
database: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}



var app = express();

console.log(__dirname);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

sql.connect(config, function (err) {

app.get('/login', require("./login.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    //console.dir(recordset);
    res.send(recordset);
});


app.get('/customers', require("./customers.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    res.send(recordset);
});

app.get('/customersReseller', require("./customersReseller.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    res.send(recordset);
});

app.get('/networks', require("./networks.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    res.send(recordset);
});

app.get('/bmmeasurements', require("./laatste_bm_metingen.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    res.send(recordset);
});

app.get('/diagnostics', require("./diagnostics.js"), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);

    res.send(recordset);
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});


});
```

Comment: Can you show all you server.js file ?

Comment: I added the complete file to my post. Thx

Comment: can you check you sql connection? or add test route app.get('/test', function(req,res) { console.log('worked'); res.end();});. It's look Like you have sql connection problems, maybe some timeout delay. And nodejs doesn't send any response to your requests.

Comment: When I do this locally, I indeed see 'worked' in my console, but on the server, there is no response to the same request

Comment: The problem is solved : I modified some user right, and modified the folder to be not read only, and now it works.